# How to deconstruct multiple nested lists in C#

Tags: c#, export-to-csv, nested-lists

I am pulling data from an API and the results are in very confusing list has some nested lists in it.  My overall goal to have the code output a .csv file that has Unit, Tag, DateTime, and Value on each line.   I figured out the first list, but the other embedded ones are out of my depth. The data returned is in a list called tagResult which has a list called value.  In the value list it has Tagname (that I want) and list called values.  the values list has the timestamp and the actual value I want.   Attached is a screenshot from a break point.

[Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr0ii.jpg)

Here is my current code.

```
namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Numerics;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using CSharpFunctionalExtensions;
    using CsvHelper;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    using Scada.OneView.Api.Client;
    using Scada.OneView.Api.Client.Abstractions;
    using Scada.OneView.Api.Client.Models.HistData;
    using Serilog;
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Initialize parameters
            const string oneViewUrl = "http://192.168.1.11/oneview4";
            const string authenticationUrl = "http://192.168.1.11/oneview4/auth/";
            const string username = "XXX";
            const string password = "SXXXXX";
            const string logFilePath = @"C:\Users\jzala\Documents\PivotGenPy\test7.txt";

            // Initialize logger
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.File(logFilePath)
            .CreateLogger();

            // Put OneView Authentication URL and username/password here
            var authenticationSettings = new OneViewAuthenticationSettings
            {
                AuthUrl = authenticationUrl,
                Username = username,
                Password = password,
                AuthenticationType = AuthenticationType.IdentityAuthentication,
            };

            // Put OneView URL here
            var oneviewSettings = new OneViewClientSettings
            {
                OneViewUrl = oneViewUrl
            };

            // Create single factory for one OneView, using oneview and authentication settings
            using var oneviewClientFactory = new OneViewClientFactory(
            oneviewSettings,
            authenticationSettings,
            Log.Logger);


            //Historical Values
            var unitGuid = new Guid("d6f49127-d710-4730-9aa1-d44846fd5537");
            var tags = new List<string>() { "WCNV.GriA2_10m_Max", "WCNV.GriA2_10m_Min", "WCNV.GriA2_10m_Std" };
            var dateFrom = new DateTime(2024, 3, 1, 10, 0, 0);
            var DateTO = new DateTime(2024, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0);
            const byte amountOfEvents = 90;


            IOneViewClient oneViewClient = oneviewClientFactory.CreateInstance();

            Result<IReadOnlyList<HistValueResponseDto>> tagResult = await oneViewClient.GetHistTagsAsync(unitGuid, tags, dateFrom,
                DateTO, 2, 2);


            if (tagResult.IsFailure)
            {
                // An error occured
                //Log.Logger.Error(tagResults.Error);
                return;
            }

            // Path of output CSV File
            string csvFilePath = @"C:\Users\jzala\Documents\PivotGenPy\test17.txt";

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(csvFilePath))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Tags,Count");
                sw.WriteLine(tagResult);

                // Iterates over the results and writes them into the file
               foreach (var d in tagResult.Value.ToList())
                {
                    //Assuming d.Value is a string and d.Count is an int
                    //sw.WriteLine($"{d.Value},{d.Count");
                    sw.WriteLine(d.TagName);
                }

                var test = tagResult.Value.ToList();
              

                //Log.Logger.Information("Historical events from OneView");
                tagResult.Value.ToList().ForEach(Value =>
                Log.Logger.Information("{@Unit},{@Tagname},{@DTTM},{@Value}",Value.TagName,Value.Values.ToList()));
                // Log.Logger.Information("Finish reading");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One of my buddies who runs software engineering at XM helped me out last night.  So here is the answer to how to unstack a nested list in an array and in a list.

```
        var dateFrom = new DateTime(2024, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    var DateTO = new DateTime(2024, 3, 11, 0, 0, 0);
    const byte amountOfEvents = 90;
    IOneViewClient oneViewClient = oneviewClientFactory.CreateInstance();
    Result<IReadOnlyList<HistValueResponseDto>> tagResult = await oneViewClient.GetHistTagsAsync(unitGuid, tags, dateFrom,
        DateTO, 10, 0);
    if (tagResult.IsFailure)
    {
        // An error occured
        Log.Logger.Error(tagResult.Error);
        return;
    }
    //Log.Logger.Information("Historical events from OneView");
    tagResult.Value.ToList().ForEach(Value =>
        Value.Values.ToList().ForEach(Values =>
       Log.Logger.Information("{@Unit},{@tagname},{@Timestamp},{@Value}", unitGuid, Value.TagName, Values.Timestamp, Values.Value)));
}
Log.Logger.Information("done");
```

}

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**